# In Python, is there a way to create a new column in Pandas, but select which row the data would start on?

Tags: python, pandas, rows, locate

Basically I want to add create a new column for each years worth of data but have it start one row down from where the last column started.

This is what it would look like in Excel
[image]

Comment: Yes that is possible., but you haven't shown any attempt to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: It is possible. I believe google can offer you some amazing insight as to how actually do to that. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to create each new column shifted down by 1.

For example, given

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'prod2018': [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, 0, 0]}, 
                  index=pd.RangeIndex(2018, 2031))
```

which looks like

```
      prod2018
2018       100
2019        90
2020        80
2021        70
2022        60
2023        50
2024        40
2025        30
2026        20
2027        10
2028         0
2029         0
2030         0
```

do

```
for i in range(2019, 2023):
    df[f'prod{i}'] = df[f'prod{i - 1}'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
```

giving

```
      prod2018  prod2019  prod2020  prod2021  prod2022
2018       100         0         0         0         0
2019        90       100         0         0         0
2020        80        90       100         0         0
2021        70        80        90       100         0
2022        60        70        80        90       100
2023        50        60        70        80        90
2024        40        50        60        70        80
2025        30        40        50        60        70
2026        20        30        40        50        60
2027        10        20        30        40        50
2028         0        10        20        30        40
2029         0         0        10        20        30
2030         0         0         0        10        20
```

Comment: Appreciate that! Started a new job, waiting on IT to install python, otherwise would have posted an attempt! I'll give it a go. Cheers.